# When is the sum non-zero?

Tags: summation

Is there an easy way to show that the following expression is non-zero only for $l=1$?

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{l} \binom{l}{k} \binom{\frac{1}{2}\left(l + k - 1\right)}{l} \frac{1 + (-1)^{k+1}}{k+2}$$

Comment: How do you define a binomial coefficient at non-integral parameters (e.g. the middle one when $k=l$)?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel $\binom{x}{l}=\frac{x(x-1)\cdots(x-l+1)}{l!}$. It's commonly used for binomial Taylor expansion, for instance.

Comment: Right, only the _bottom_ parameter has to be integral for a finite expression.

Comment: But what does it mean for a binomial coefficient? if the upper number is smaller than the lower one, as it can happen in this sum? Select 3 balls out of 2?

Comment: @Luke: By the expansion egreg quoted you would get $\binom 23=\frac{2\cdot 1\cdot 0}{3!}=0$ ways to select 3 balls out of 2.

Comment: (Don't ask me what sense it makes that there is $1$ way to select $4$ balls out of $-1$, though ...)

Comment: For negative numbers, the analytic extension of the Gamma function is used. Well, maybe I should rephrase the question: is there any way of showing this?